# Regular expression - check for optional ' /' in sthe string

Tags: regex

I have this regular expresion

```
/\[found:([a-zA-Z0-9-_: |=\.]+)]/
```

that checks if my string contains things like this for example:

```
[found:user id=1|class=admin]
```

However there are some cases where my pattern may look like this:

```
[found:user id=1|class=admin /]
```

so basicly it has an optional ' /' at the end. How can I put this in my regex?

Comment: Use this regex
`\[found:([a-zA-Z0-9-_: |=\.]+)(\s\/)*]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
/\[found:([a-zA-Z0-9-_: |=\.]+)(\s*\/)?]/
```

If the space isn't optional then use `\s` instead of `\s*` or `\s+` for at least one space.